# Querying MongoDB collection by array intersection

Tags: node.js, mongodb

What I have:

- An array of strings that I wish to query with. `['a', 'b', 'c']`

Data I'm querying against:

- A collection of objects of type `foo`, all with a `bar` field. The `bar` field is an array of strings, the same type as the one I'm querying with, potentially with some of the same elements.

`foo1 = { bar: ['a'] }`

`foo2 = { bar: ['d'] }`

`foo3 = { bar: ['a', 'c']}`

What I need:

- A query that returns all `foo` objects whose entire `bar` array is contained within the query array. In the example above, I'd want `foo1` and `foo3` to come back

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using **aggregation**

you might need to use `$setIsSubset` in aggregate pipeline

```
db.col.aggregate(
    [
        {$project : { bar : 1 , isSubset: { $setIsSubset : [ "$bar" , ['a','b','c'] ] }}}, 
        {$match : { isSubset : true}}
    ]
)
```

collection

```
> db.col.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5a6420d984eeec7b0b2f767b"), "bar" : [ "a" ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5a6420d984eeec7b0b2f767c"), "bar" : [ "a", "c" ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5a6420d984eeec7b0b2f767d"), "bar" : [ "d" ] }
```

aggregate

```
> db.col.aggregate([{$project : { bar : 1 , isSubset: { $setIsSubset : [ "$bar" , ['a','b','c'] ] }}}, {$match : {isSubset : true}}])
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5a6420d984eeec7b0b2f767b"), "bar" : [ "a" ], "isSubset" : true }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5a6420d984eeec7b0b2f767c"), "bar" : [ "a", "c" ], "isSubset" : true }
>
```

**EDIT**

using **find** with `$expr`

```
db.col.find({$expr : { $setIsSubset : [ "$bar" , ['a','b','c'] ] }})
```

result

```
> db.col.find({$expr : { $setIsSubset : [ "$bar" , ['a','b','c'] ] }})
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5a6420d984eeec7b0b2f767b"), "bar" : [ "a" ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5a6420d984eeec7b0b2f767c"), "bar" : [ "a", "c" ] }
>
```

Comment: Thanks!
I ended up using `$addFields` instead of `$project`, but your answer led me to the right path